# Number format with Locale gives wrong output

Tags: java, numbers, locale

I want Norwegian currency format. My code is

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("no","NO"));
        System.out.println(numberFormat.format(188800.99));
```

It gives output 188 800,99. But the Norwegian number pattern is 188.800,99
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: I don't think that documentation is correct. If I use a German Locale it actually outputs your desired output with . as thousand separator instead of space, which is different from what the documentation claims it should be. But that is what I expected, because I've been using NumberFormat for German Locale in Java code since ages and never have I seen it produce output with space a thousand-separator as the documentation claims.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS That documentation is quite weird I would say. From what I can tell it is a documentation to the Solaris system or something like that and not really related to Java and it's NumberFormat implementation. It was the first thing that showed up in google when I searched for Norwegian number formatting but not sure how reliable it is.

Comment: 1. There's no "no_NO" locale (or [at least there shouldn't be](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=532487)). The correct one is *either* `nb_NO` or `nn_NO`, depending on which one you want. 2. The CLDR (which is where this data comes from) will change over time to more correctly represent the current state of writing, so it's possible that the result *is* now correct (but I'm not from norway, so I can't confirm or deny that). Check the CLDR survey tool

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that patterns in given countries are defined in official documents/standards. In the link you've provided the correct pattern in Norway is indeed 188.800,99 but when I checked on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use) it says that 188 800,99 would be correct format in Norway.

As a solution you could either search for a `NumberFormat` that fits you needs or you could create your own, just like so:

```
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
numberFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(1881212800.9));
```

It prints the number as `1.881.212.800,90`. In the pattern `#,##0.00` the hashes represent optional numbers and zeros required numbers. In this case there will always be at least a single number to the left of the comma and two to the right of it.